# Can we add parameters to the default traces generated by spring-cloud-sleuth?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud-sleuth, open-telemetry, distributed-tracing

I have integrated spring-cloud-sleuth with my Spring-boot application. I have also used open-telemetry as the log  exporter. When I call a REST API in my application, I can see a span being generated. However, this span does not have information about parameters to the method/API. Is there a way that it can be added?
I did not find anything related in the documentation

Answer (score -1):

you can try using sleuth this helps you to set the context of the variables you are using, for this you must include the name of the service:
(%{spring.zipkin.service.name})
I hope this helps

https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-sleuth/reference/html/#log-integration

Comment: As I mentioned in the original question, I have already used spring-cloud-sleuth. The thing is I have not found a way to include method parameters in the traces